# Is there a built-in javascript function similar to os.path.join?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a built-in javascript (client-side) function that functions similarly to Node's `path.join`? I know I can join strings in the following manner:

```
['a', 'b'].join('/')
```

The problem is that if the strings already contain a leading/trailing "/", then they will not be joined correctly, e.g.:

```
['a/','b'].join('/')
```

Comment: you can transfrom [this php code](https://github.com/JosephMoniz/php-path) (or similar) into javascript to be used in both node and browser if needed

Comment: Aren't double `//` resolved universally as a single `/` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There isn't currently a built-in that will perform a join while preventing duplicate separators. If you want concise, I'd just write your own:

```
function pathJoin(parts, sep){
   var separator = sep || '/';
   var replace   = new RegExp(separator+'{1,}', 'g');
   return parts.join(separator).replace(replace, separator);
}
```

This can be simplified with modern javascript:

```js
const pathJoin = (parts, sep='/') => parts.join(sep).replace(new RegExp(sep+'{1,}', 'g'), sep);

console.log(pathJoin(['a/', 'b', 'c//']))
```

Comment: this doesn't work for combining http:// links. eg: pathJoin(['http://google.com/', '/my/path/']) will return http:/google.com/my/path, which isn't a valid url because of the http:/ (single slash)

Comment: @Berty It's expected. I don't use Java, but judging by the name `os.path.join`, I'm assuming it's intended for _file_ paths on the local filesystem. This is why many languages, including JS/Node, have different methods for creating paths for URL's vs filesystems. Node's built-in `path` module does the same, however, you can use the `URL` module to handle your example.

Comment: This can be simplified to `function pathJoin(paths, sep='/') {
    return paths.join(sep).replace(/\/{1,}/g, sep);
}` :)

Answer (score 31):

Use the [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module. [`path.join`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2) is exactly what you're looking for. [From the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2):

> `path.join([path1][, path2][, ...])#`
> Join all arguments together and normalize the resulting path.
>
> Arguments must be strings. In v0.8, non-string arguments were silently ignored. In v0.10 and up, an exception is thrown.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> const path = require('node:path')
>   
> path.join('/foo', 'bar', 'baz/asdf', 'quux', '..')
> // returns
> '/foo/bar/baz/asdf'
>
> path.join('foo', {}, 'bar')
> // throws exception
> TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
> ```

You can also use `import path from 'path'` instead of `const path = require('node:path')` if you're loading modules with that style.

**Edit:**

I assumed here that you're using server-side Javascript like node.js. If you want to use it in the browser, you can use [path-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-browserify).

Comment: Should have specified, but I was asking about client-side. path-browserify seems useful, though.

Comment: Behaves differently. Python os.path.join also supports URIs. If you supply a full URI as the second argument it will not try and append the URI. It will return the URI.

Answer (score 23):

Building on @Berty's reply, this ES6 variant preserves all leading slashes, to work with [protocol relative url's](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) (like `//stackoverflow.com`), and also ignores any empty parts:

```js
build_path = (...args) => {
  return args.map((part, i) => {
    if (i === 0) {
      return part.trim().replace(/[\/]*$/g, '')
    } else {
      return part.trim().replace(/(^[\/]*|[\/]*$)/g, '')
    }
  }).filter(x=>x.length).join('/')
}
```

- `build_path("http://google.com/", "my", "path")` will return `"http://google.com/my/path"`
- `build_path("//a", "", "/", "/b/")` will return `"//a/b"`
- `build_path()` will return `""`

Note that this regex strips trailing slashes. Sometimes a trailing slash carries semantic meaning (e.g. denoting a directory rather than a file), and that distinction will be lost here.

Comment: The code is buggy. I tried `build_path("http://", "/foo/bar", "index.html")` and it returned `'http:/foo/bar/index.html'`.

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer doesn't work for URLs, it removes the double slash after the protocol
`https://hostname` becomes `https:/hostname`.

Most other answers do not handle the first and last part differently. A slash at the beginning or end should not be removed, it would change the meaning (relative/absolute) (file/directory) of the joined path.

Below is a modified version of the accepted answer:

```
function pathJoin(parts, sep){
    const separator = sep || '/';
    parts = parts.map((part, index)=>{
        if (index) {
            part = part.replace(new RegExp('^' + separator), '');
        }
        if (index !== parts.length - 1) {
            part = part.replace(new RegExp(separator + '$'), '');
        }
        return part;
    })
    return parts.join(separator);
 }
```

usage:

```
console.log(pathJoin(['https://', 'hostname', 'path/'])); // 'https://hostname/path/'
console.log(pathJoin(['relative/', 'path', 'to/dir/']));  // 'relative/path/to/dir/'
console.log(pathJoin(['/absolute/', 'path', 'to/file'])); // '/absolute/path/to/file'
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tdsLencu/

Comment: This is better, but still fails on `file` URLS. POSIX file paths start with three slashes (ie: `file:///foo/bar`), as there's no domain name or port before the path, but your function strips the slash at the start of the path if it immediately follows the scheme (ie: `file://foo/bar`).

Comment: The function assumes you are using the correct number of slashes for the protocol. (```https:/``` and ```http:``` are not automagically fixed). If you feel that the 'correct' number of slashes for the file: prefix is '//' and the third slash is caused by the empty host name, than you should add the empty hostname as parameter ```pathJoin(['file://', '', 'path']);``` If you don't feel the need for an empty hostname, you should provide ```file:///``` as the first element```

Comment: That's just silly. Calling a web-based `path.join` function with the args `("file://", "/foo)` or `("file://", "foo")` should return `"file:///foo"`. The whole point and purpose of the function is to ensure the correct number of separators at the concatenation sites *because you cannot control whether or not they contain slashes*. In practice, you don't pass a bunch of string literals to the function, as you may as well just use a string literal. At least one of the args is a variable. Whether it includes a slash or not is unknown, else the function is pointless.

Comment: In both cases (`("file://", "/foo)` and `("file://", "foo")`), the args are valid, and the scheme has the correct number of slashes (2). The third slash is part of the path. And I don't "feel" this is correct. There's an official specification that says so.

Answer (score 4):

You may find the code on this gist ["Simple path join and dirname functions for generic javascript"](https://gist.github.com/creationix/7435851) useful  (i.e both in node and browser)

```js
// Joins path segments.  Preserves initial "/" and resolves ".." and "."
// Does not support using ".." to go above/outside the root.
// This means that join("foo", "../../bar") will not resolve to "../bar"
function join(/* path segments */) {
  // Split the inputs into a list of path commands.
  var parts = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++) {
    parts = parts.concat(arguments[i].split("/"));
  }
  // Interpret the path commands to get the new resolved path.
  var newParts = [];
  for (i = 0, l = parts.length; i < l; i++) {
    var part = parts[i];
    // Remove leading and trailing slashes
    // Also remove "." segments
    if (!part || part === ".") continue;
    // Interpret ".." to pop the last segment
    if (part === "..") newParts.pop();
    // Push new path segments.
    else newParts.push(part);
  }
  // Preserve the initial slash if there was one.
  if (parts[0] === "") newParts.unshift("");
  // Turn back into a single string path.
  return newParts.join("/") || (newParts.length ? "/" : ".");
}

// A simple function to get the dirname of a path
// Trailing slashes are ignored. Leading slash is preserved.
function dirname(path) {
  return join(path, "..");
}
```

**Note** similar implementations (which may be transformed to js code as well) exist for [php here](https://github.com/JosephMoniz/php-path)

Comment: No license was specified on the original work, and public domain isn't a thing everywhere. This is so beautifully commented I'd love to see it with a proper license.  :(

Comment: They should do like sqlite and offer a license to anyone afraid of the public domain risk for $1000

Answer (score 2):

My approach to solve this problem:

```
var path = ['a/','b'].map(function (i) {
    return i.replace(/(^\/|\/$)/, '');
}).join('/');
```

Second method:

```
var path = ['a/','b'].join('/').replace(/\/{2,}/, '/')
```

Comment: This seems good, but you may also want to replace forward slashes in the beginning of each string.

Comment: First approach returns 'a//b' if a path element has leading and trailing slashes, e.g. ['/a/', 'b'].

Comment: @McCroskey you can fix that by changing the regex to: /(^\/|\/$)/g

Answer (score 2):

This one makes sure it works with http:// links without removing the double slash.
It trims the slashes at the beginning and end of each part. Then joins them seperated by '/'

```js
/**
 * Joins 2 paths together and makes sure there aren't any duplicate seperators
 * @param parts the parts of the url to join. eg: ['http://google.com/', '/my-custom/path/']
 * @param separator The separator for the path, defaults to '/'
 * @returns {string} The combined path
 */
function joinPaths(parts, separator) {
  return parts.map(function(part) { return part.trim().replace(/(^[\/]*|[\/]*$)/g, ''); }).join(separator || '/');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not, however it is pretty easy to implement. This could also be solved with a regex but its not too bad without one.

```
var pathJoin = function(pathArr){
    return pathArr.map(function(path){
        if(path[0] === "/"){
            path = path.slice(1);        
        }
        if(path[path.length - 1] === "/"){
            path = path.slice(0, path.length - 1);   
        }
        return path;     
    }).join("/");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/swoogie/gfy50cm1/

Answer (score 1):

```js
function joinPath(...input) {      
  let paths = input
    .filter((path) => !!path) // Remove undefined | null | empty
    .join("/") //Join to string
    .replaceAll("\\", "/") // Replace from \ to /
    .split("/") 
    .filter((path) => !!path && path !== ".") // Remove empty in case a//b///c or ./a ./b
    .reduce(
      (items, item) =>{
        item === ".." ? items.pop() : items.push(item);
        return items
      },        
      []
    ) // Jump one levep if ../  
 ;
  
  if(input[0] && input[0].startsWith('/')) paths.unshift("")
  
  return paths.join("/") || (paths.length ? "/" : ".");
}

let test = [      
  [],
  ["./"],
  ["./a"],
  ["/a"],
  ["a", "b", "c", "./d", "/e/", "f", "g", "h"],
  ["/a", "/b/", "../c", "./d", "e", "../f", "g", "h"],
  ["/a", "b/", "/c/", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
];

test
  .map((item) => joinPath(...item))
  .map((item) => {
    document.writeln(item);
    document.writeln("<br>");
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what @leo did:

```
export function buildPath(...args: string[]): string {
  const [first] = args;
  const firstTrimmed = first.trim();
  const result = args
    .map((part) => part.trim())
    .map((part, i) => {
      if (i === 0) {
        return part.replace(/[/]*$/g, '');
      } else {
        return part.replace(/(^[/]*|[/]*$)/g, '');
      }
    })
    .filter((x) => x.length)
    .join('/');

  return firstTrimmed === '/' ? `/${result}` : result;
}
```

Should cover following scenarios:

```
  [
    {
      input: ['/'],
      result: '/',
    },
    {
      input: ['/', 'aaa', ':id'],
      result: '/aaa/:id',
    },
    {
      input: ['/bbb', ':id'],
      result: '/bbb/:id',
    },
    {
      input: ['ccc', ':id'],
      result: 'ccc/:id',
    },
    {
      input: ['/', '/', '/', '/ddd/', '/', ':id'],
      result: '/ddd/:id',
    },
    {
      input: ['', '', '', 'eee', '', ':id'],
      result: 'eee/:id',
    },
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the other solutions contain bugs, are difficult to understand, and support features that are redundant in the browser, so I wrote my own (derived from the others). This version adds support for `file` URLs and removes support for Windows paths.

```js
const join = function(...parts) {

    /* This function takes zero or more strings, which are concatenated
    together to form a path or URL, which is returned as a string. This
    function intelligently adds and removes slashes as required, and is
    aware that `file` URLs will contain three adjacent slashes. */

    const [first, last, slash] = [0, parts.length - 1, "/"];

    const matchLeadingSlash = new RegExp("^" + slash);
    const matchTrailingSlash = new RegExp(slash + "$");

    parts = parts.map(function(part, index) {

        if (index === first && part === "file://") return part;

        if (index > first) part = part.replace(matchLeadingSlash, "");

        if (index < last) part = part.replace(matchTrailingSlash, "");

        return part;
    });

    return parts.join(slash);
};
```