# Is there a Path.Combine() type method in JavaScript/jQuery similar to .NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

.NET has a Path.Combine() method which will concatenate multiple path parts into a single clean path:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx

Is there a similar JavaScript or jQuery function I can use for urls?  This would mean that slashes in the url would be added as needed and/or duplicate slashes would be removed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using server-side Javascript like **node.js** you can use `path.join`.

If you want to use it in the browser (*client-side*), there isn't currently a built-in function that will perform a join. 
You will have to use you own function. Or you can use ready made functions like  [url-join.js](https://github.com/jfromaniello/url-join/blob/master/lib/url-join.js).

[Have a look at this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29855282)